# Adding Folders in App_LocalResources

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I want to add folders to keep things organized in `App_LocalResources`. Because when adding a lot of resorce files for different languages in this folder, files are getting messy. I added folders like

- **Default.aspx** *(Folder)*

  - Default.aspx.en.resx
  - Default.aspx.sp.resx
- **Contact.aspx** *(Folder)*

  - Contact.aspx.en.resx
  - Contact.aspx.en.resx

But they didn't work.

Can you guys tell me how to make it work.

Thanks.

**Edit :**

FYI : Actually what I did is working. I mean the way I mentioned above is the correct way. The reason why it wasn't working is something else so you can define your folders and the resource files above.

Hope it helps others...

Comment: How are you adding these? Via the Tools menu? how are you getting them into your project?

Comment: I am adding with New Folder option in Visual Studio 2010...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what I did is working. I mean the way I mentioned above is the correct way. The reason why it wasn't working is something else so you can define your folders and the resource files above.

Hope it helps others...

Since I want this question help others, I am not gonna delete it.